# Pandas rounding values of a dataframe when comparing to a given value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a strange problem.
I have a dataframe df. I want to create another dataframe df2 out of the first one by rejecting all the rows that have 'position' (name of the column) values between 2.750 and 3.250.
I have done that many times as followed:

```
df_a = df[(df['position'] < 2.750)]
df_b = df[((df['position'] > 3.250)]
df2 = pd.concat([df_a, df_b])
```

The problem is that, when the value of the column is like 2.750003 or even 2.75, it seems like pandas rounds the value and then the row is kept even though it should be rejected.

Does anyone have a suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your observation. Also worth considering is `pd.Series.between`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html

Comment: You want `position` smaller than 2.75 and greater than `3.25` at the same time?

Comment: Would be good to show (relevant parts of) your dataframe, the result you get vs. what you expect.

Comment: Sorry the code that I showed wasn't the good one, I just edited it.

Comment: Yes @Ynjxsjmh, I do want both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reject everything between 2.75 and 3.25, you can use:

```
out = df[(df['position'] < 2.750) | (df['position'] > 3.250)]
```

Or:

```
out = df[~df['position'].between(2.75, 3.250)]
```

Example output:

```
   position
0   1.00000
1   2.00000
2   2.74000
7   3.25001
8   4.00000
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'position': [1,
                                2,
                                2.74,
                                2.75,         #
                                2.750000001,  # should be
                                3,            # rejected
                                3.25,         #
                                3.25001,
                                4,
                               ]})
```

Comment: Should you use .loc like  df.loc[(df['position'] < 2.750) | (df['position'] > 3.250)]. Because otherwise you aren´t coping the values from the first df, instead referencing them.

Comment: @PoderPsittacus it depends what OP wants to do, but yes `loc` is safer